# How to disable Ctrl+C in ASP.NET Core host

Tags: asp.net-core

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

I don't want to use <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> to shut down the application

Comment: What is the problem with ctrl+C ? Could you elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

You can run your task in background, either by following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio), but I simply prefer using `&` after your program name, it will be executed in the background (if linux), and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1168587/how-to-run-an-exe-application-as-a-background-task-on-startup) you have the solution for windows

```
dotnet core run &
```

Because it is in the background it is harder to interrupt, you have to find the pid (linux, mac os) or open control task manager (windows)

Comment: No, I mean in the application code
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().ConfigureWebHostDefaults (...

Answer (score 0):

You can use **IWebHost.RunAsync()** method. This version does not wait for CTRL+C

An example:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder() 
.UseKestrel(opt => {  })
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.Build();

CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
await host.RunAsync(cts.Token);
```

On the output you will not see anymore the message "Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.". When you press CTRL+C it will be routed to the main thread from the input pipe as usual.

```
Starting HTTP Server on port 8080..
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: D:\wwwroot\
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
Now listening on: http://localhost:8080
```