# ASP.NET core seems to be breaking default ctrl+c behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a process with some computations in c#. I usually run it either in console on windows or in docker container on Linux.
But I am seeking for a general answer which I would like to be applicable also to other types of apps such as windows service or WPF app.

I want my process to react to the application shutdown. I want to save all the computation, leave the hard drive in a consistent state, and dispose of some resources before the process ends.

I used to do it like this:

```
class Program
{
    // longRunningTasks can be cancelled by CancellationToken from processExitTokenSource source 
    static Task longRunningTasks;
    static readonly CancellationTokenSource processExitTokenSource = new();

    static async Task doTheMainJob(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // the long running computations I am interested in
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I expect this line to be written to console when ctrl+c is pressed or when process is to be closed by other means.");
        processExitTokenSource.Cancel();
        // this waits for task to end
        longRunningTasks.Wait();
        // aplication should exit after this line is reached
    }

    static async Task Main()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_ProcessExit);
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        tasks.Add(doTheMainJob(cancellationToken))
        if (Settings.AllowMonitoringThroughHttp) {
            tasks.Add(WebServer.RunAsync(cancellationToken));
        }
        longRunningTasks = Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
        await longRunningTasks;
    }
}
```

It always worked.
Now I wanted to be modern and I added simple web server Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc server to monitor the process.

```
class WebServer
{
    public static async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new string[0]);
        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

        var app = builder.Build();
        app.MapControllers();
        await app.RunAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

The server listens to some port and replies to http request flawlessly. However it seems to somehow override the ctrl+c behavior and CurrentDomain_ProcessExit method is never called. Hence processExitTokenSource is never Canceled and my computations are never canceled.

What hapens? And how do I configure the web server to behave normally? I want to cancel it myself by cancelation token.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68534062/disable-ctrlc-shutdown-in-asp-net-core-web-api-application) answers how to disable Ctrl+C key.

Here we do not want to disable the key but restore its behavior to the default. The closes approximation of the original behavior I could get was by using Console.CancelKeyPress which starts a task which calls `Environment.Exit(0)`.

`Environment.Exit(0)` cannot be called from the same thread as it would cause dead lock. `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit` event would wait for WebApplication to exit and WebApplication would wait for Environment.Exit(0) to end.

```
public class NoopConsoleLifetime : IHostLifetime, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ILogger<NoopConsoleLifetime> _logger;

        public NoopConsoleLifetime(ILogger<NoopConsoleLifetime> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("StopAsync was called");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task WaitForStartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // without this ctrl+c just kills the application
            Console.CancelKeyPress += OnCancelKeyPressed;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private void OnCancelKeyPressed(object? sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Ctrl+C has been pressed, ignoring.");
            // e.Cancel = false would turn off the application without the clean up
            e.Cancel = true;
            // not running in task causes dead lock
            // Environment.Exit calls the ProcessExit event which waits for web server which waits for this method to end
            Task.Run(() => Environment.Exit(0));
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.CancelKeyPress -= OnCancelKeyPressed;
        }
    }
```

Just add NoopConsoleLifeTime to dependency injection container.

`builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHostLifetime, NoopConsoleLifetime>();`